# put all the data tables names of a given database in an array

Tags: php

How to obtain only the data tabels names after being connected to a mysql database.

```
$query = $db1->prepare('show tables');
    $query->execute();
     $Columns = array();
     $index = 0;
     while($rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         var_dump($rows);
         $Columns[$index] = $row;
         $index++;
                 }
```

I want to obtain a list like this:[tabel1,table2...]
but the result of the line 6 is:

```
array(1) { ["Tables_in_database_name"]=> string(5) "tabel1" } array(1) { ["Tables_in_database_name"]=> string(10) "Datacamera" } array(1) { ["Tables_in_datacam"]=> string(7) "......." } }
```

what is the php command that can be added to extract only data tables names?

Comment: Its easy to parse that array to leave only the desired values there.

Comment: I know that I have to parse the array to filter it and get the desired values but I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

Please try

```
$query = $db1->prepare('show tables');
$query->execute();
 $Columns = array();
 while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
     $Columns[] = $row[0];
 }
```

Comment: it displays: 
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "xxxxxx" } array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "xxxxxxxxxx" } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "xxxxxxx" } } with xxx are datatables names

Comment: output is: string(6) "xxxxxx" string(10) "xxxxxxxxxx" string(7) "xxxxxxx"

Comment: I tried $row[0][0] but it displays only the first letter of the every data table name string(1) "x" string(1) "x" string(1) "x

Comment: use `$row[0]` please answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL then you can get this as a normal result set from the information_schema database using the following query:-

```
select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE';
```

You may need to give your applications user SELECT access to the information_schema database.